# Text not aligned with image

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

### Scenario

I've got the following code:

```css
html body{
 font-family:Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
 background-color:white;
}
.title{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Material design!</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="title"><img src='http://stubborn.altervista.org/options.png'> Material design!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### What the code should do

Displaying a fixed header with the title "Material Design!" and an icon

### What isn't working

Text and icon are not aligned

### My question

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could downvoter and closevoter kindly explain the reason of their vote? I can't understand how my question could be "Too broad". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see if you add a yellow outline to the image, they are aligned. The bottom of the image sits on the same line as the text.

```css
html body{
 font-family:Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
 background-color:white;
}
.title{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px grey;
}

img { outline: solid yellow 1px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Material design!</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="title"><img src='http://stubborn.altervista.org/options.png'> Material design!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can adjust that with `vertical-align`:

```css
html body{
 font-family:Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
 background-color:white;
}
.title{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px grey;
}

img { outline: solid yellow 1px; vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Material design!</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="title"><img src='http://stubborn.altervista.org/options.png'> Material design!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

… but ultimately you'll probably want to edit the image to adjust the amount of whitespace it has in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.title img{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, using the code you provided the image is lower than the text

Comment: Play a little around with it by trying other values: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

You just need to vertically align the icon:

```css
html body{
 font-family:Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
 background-color:white;
}
.title{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px grey;
}
.title img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Material design!</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="title"><img src='http://stubborn.altervista.org/options.png'> Material design!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, using the code you provided the image is lower than the text.

Comment: @Stubborn Then adjust it. Instead of `middle` set it to something like `-6px`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```css
html body{
 font-family:Arial,Verdana,Geneva;
 background-color:white;
}
.title{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 line-height:30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px grey;
}

span{
  background-image: url("http://stubborn.altervista.org/options.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Material design!</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="title"><span> Material design!</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can `float` left image an change `padding` left.

or you can `vertical-align`: middle for image
good luck